# Google LineChart Won't Draw

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, pygooglechart

I have the following javascript for a LineChart that checks out using JSHint but refuses to display:

```js
// Load the LineChart charting package
google.load("visualization", "1", {
  packages: ["corechart", "line", "LineChart"]
});
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Callback that creates and populates a data table,
// instantiates the line chart, passes in the data and
// draws it.
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
  data.addrows([
    [new Date(2015, 2, 30), 419.5],
    [new Date(2015, 2, 31), 497.51],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 1), 1465.85],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 2), 2594.71],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 4), 2620.7],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 5), 3189.86],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 6), 4172.96],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 7), 4332.96],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 8), 4653.03],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 9), 4678.98],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 12), 5626.48],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 13), 9779.28],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 14), 10428.3],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 15), 10647.18],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 17), 10815.58],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 20), 11471.58],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 21), 11875.57],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 22), 12052.07],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 23), 13461.14],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 24), 14072.78],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 25), 14199.78],
    [new Date(2015, 3, 27), 14320.28],
    [new Date(2015, 4, 27), 100000]
  ]);
  var options = {};
  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart', 'timeline','LineChart']}]}">
</script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

So, what am I doing wrong? I have attempted several date construction methods including:

```
    [new Date('2015-3-30'), 419.5],
```

Comment: Have you looked at the console for errors? When I tried to run it it said you need to use the `new` keyword. When I added that it said it was trying to call an undefined function because you call `getrows` instead of `getRows`.

Comment: Oops, make that `addrows` vs `addRows`. Now I get an error that says `You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView`. Not sure why yet though

Comment: @redbmk, Thanks you for both of your comments!!! Correcting both of the problems you so aptly pointed out solved the issue. I am new to this forum and don't know how to mark this question as "Answered" but it has been.

Comment: I added an answer so that you can accept it. How did you fix the other error though, about the wrong type of data? Or did you not get that when you tried on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the `new` keyword before instantiating `DataTable`, which can be seen as an error message in the console. Also, there's a typo when adding rows. It should be `addRows` instead of `addrows`.

Try changing

```
var data = google.visualization.DataTable();
  // ...
data.addrows([
  // ...
```

to

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  // ...
data.addRows([
  // ...
```